# What are value type frameworks?

Tags: delphi, orm, frameworks, value-type

I often come across value type frameworks mentioned in relation to OPFs and ORMs targeting old Delphi versions prior to D2010, but I don't understand what they are. What are value type frameworks?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that this is not a discussion forum - "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" and not "extended discussion questions," as our excellent FAQ says: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I edited the post trying to rescue it :-) a) Remove misleading personal opinion on Rtti v.s. VTF b) Asking explicitly for concise answers.

Comment: Seems like a decent question to me, @Piskvor. Menjaraz would like someone to explain value type frameworks. It's not a request for discussion; it's a request for a definition.

Comment: Value types are explained here [ORM Basics: Entities, Values, Roles, and Facts](http://www.proace.com/2010/02/17/orm-basics-entities-values-roles-and-facts/)

Comment: I thought ORM stood for Object-Relational Modelling and had to do with the Object to Relational impedance mismatch. But now ORM means Object-Role modelling?  YAFTLA. You tagged this ORM and ORM is defined here on SO as "Object Relational Mapping", but the link from mjn discusses Object-Role Modelling, something ELSE.